Stryker Mutation testing not working react with webpack
When I integrated stryker in my react with webpack configiration application its behaving weard.
Getting error like react scripts module not found but this module already installed and react app working already.
Can someone please help me on this.
I tried stryker-core and stryker-javascript module.
